# Using Eulers method to solve equation of motion of aircraft

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, eulers-method

I am told I can solve the following differential equation by utilising Euler's method. I can solve simple differential equations with the method, I am however, having some trouble wrapping my head around [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGl8R.png)
problem.

$F_thrust$ = Force applied to aircraft

$C_D$ = drag coefficient

$ρ$ = air density

$A$ = wing area

$v^2$ = airspeed in m/s

As mentioned I am a bit stumped by this so any pointers would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your diff. equation is briefly written as it follows:
$$\frac{dv}{dt} = f(t,v)\tag1$$

If we mesh the time from $t^0$ to $t^N$ making steps of length $\delta t=(t^N-t^0)/N$, one can approximate the derivative of $v$ with respect to time (forward $\textit{Taylor}$'s expansion) as 
$$\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right)^{n}\approx \frac{v^{n+1}-v^{n}}{\delta t}$$
Hence  the equation $(1)$ can be discretised 
$$\frac{v^{n+1}-v^{n}}{\delta t}=f(t^n,v^n)$$
Rearranging terms one obtains the explicit method, called $\textit{Euler}$'s method
$$v^{n+1} = v^n+\delta t\,f(t^n,v^n)\tag2$$

From wher, provided one initial contition, $\textit{i.e.}$ $v^0=v_0$, recursively from $(2)$ one can obtain the rest of the values of the solution.